# What is the difference between loop/recur and recur by itself?

Tags: recursion, clojure, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization

I'm having trouble finding the answer to this in the Clojure docs. I'm new to Clojure and it seems as though you can use `recur` in two different ways and essentially get the same result.

Example 1:

```
(defn my-function [num]
  (if (> num 10)
    num
    (recur (+ num 1))))
```

Example 2:

```
(defn my-function [num]
  (loop [cnt num]
    (if (> cnt 10)
      cnt
      (recur (+ cnt 1)))))
```

From what I can tell, these two forms seem to do the exact same thing. I understand that the reason `recur` is good generally is that under the right circumstances the compiler can hack together some kind of pseudo-tail-call-optimization, which I really like and would love to make use of as often as possible. So here are my questions:

1. What is the need for using `loop` when `recur` seems to work without it?
2. Does `loop` just create a "recursion scope" kind of like how `let` creates a mini scope?
3. If so, can I still get the tail recursion benefits without using `loop`?

Comment: With `loop` you can accept (and pass) arbitrary set of parameters, without `loop` you must pass only what function can accept.

Comment: That makes sense. I believe that can answer questions 1 and 2. What about the third?

Comment: It must be a tail call, otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: Your examples are suspect. You should have `if` instead of `when` in both. I've taken the liberty of correcting them (I hope!),

Comment: @Thumbnail thanks for the code edit. As I said, I'm new to Clojure. Question for you though, when is it appropriate to use `when` instead of `if`?

Comment: @Thumbnail nevermind I figured it out. `when` does not use an else clause. It's essentially a `do` block with a condition at the beginning.

Comment: Yes. And the `cnt`s have no side effect, hence are quite redundant in the middle of a `when` form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to answer your questions one by one:

1. `loop` allows you to accept and pass arbitrary parameters. Without `loop` you would be limited with only being able to pass only what function accepts. It would lead to heaps of tiny auxiliary functions
2. Yep, kind of
3. It must be a tail call and it's constrained by compiler

Answer (score 5):

1. There is *never* any need to use `loop`. You can *always* replace it
   with a call to an anonymous `fn` form.
2. Yes. `loop` acts as a `let` that doubles as a recursion point for
   `recur`. If a `loop` catches no `recur`s, you can replace it with a
   `let`, and vice versa.
3. Yes. It's `recur` that implements tail recursion (and only tail
   recursion), whether it recurs to a `loop` or a `fn` form.

To illustrate (1), you can replace the `loop` form in example 2

```
  (loop [cnt num]
    (if (> cnt 10)
      cnt
      (recur (+ cnt 1))))
```

... with

```
((fn [cnt] (if (> cnt 10) cnt (recur (+ cnt 1)))) num)
```

... which, as you see, creates and calls an anonymous function.

You can even write `loop` as a macro that makes this transformation:

```
(defmacro loop [bindings & body]
  (let [[names values] (apply map vector (partition 2 bindings))]
    `((fn ~names ~@body) ~@values)))


(loop [i 10, ans 0]
  (case i
    0 ans
    (recur (dec i) (+ ans i))))
; 55
```

This may be slower than the proper `clojure.core/loop`.